# How do I split up a search string to allow for quoted text?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

I want to make a list of strings from the text of a search field.
I want to make anything that is in double quotes be split out.

ex.
`sample' "string's are, more "text" making" 12.34,hello"pineapple sundays`

Produces

```
sample' 
string's are, more_  //underscore shown to display space
text
 making
12.34
hello
pineapple
sundays
```

Edit: Here is my (somewhat) elegant solution, thanks for the help everyone!

```
Private Function GetSearchTerms(ByVal searchText As String) As String()
    'Clean search string of unwanted characters'
    searchText = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(searchText, "[^a-zA-Z0-9""'.,= ]", "")

    'Guarantees the first entry will not be an entry in quotes if the searchkeywords starts with double quotes'
    Dim searches As String() = searchText.Replace("""", " "" ").Split("""")
    Dim myWords As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String) = New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)
    Dim delimiters As String() = New String() {" ", ","}

    For index As Integer = 0 To searches.Length - 1
        'even is regular text, split up into individual search terms'
        If (index Mod 2 = 0) Then
            myWords.AddRange(searches(index).Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        Else
            'check for unclosed double quote, if so, split it up and add, space we added earlier will get split out'
            If (searches.Length Mod 2 = 0 And index = searches.Length - 1) Then
                myWords.AddRange(searches(index).Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            Else
                '2 double quotes found'
                'remove the 2 spaces that we added earlier'
                Dim myQuotedString As String = searches(index).Substring(1, searches(index).Length - 2)
                If (myQuotedString.Length > 0) Then
                    myWords.Add(myQuotedString)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return myWords.ToArray()
End Function
```

Oi, vb commenting is ugly, anyone know how to clean this up?

Comment: There are 5 quotes in my sample string. I want to ignore the last one that has no corresponding end quote.

Comment: I'm going to be splitting on spaces and commas on everything outside quotes.

Comment: Be careful if you do that, cause if you split based on two characters sometimes the Split Function will actually split the string twice, once at the first char and second at the second char, meaning you will get a line of blank data in the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not THE COMPLETE solution since it is missing few validation checks, but it has everything you need.

My CharOccurs() finds occurrences of `'"'` and stores them into list in order.

```
public static List<int> CharOccurs(string stringToSearch, char charToFind)
        {
            List<int> count = new List<int>();
            int  chr = 0;
            while (chr != -1)
            {
                chr = stringToSearch.IndexOf(charToFind, chr);
                if (chr != -1)
                {
                    count.Add(chr);
                    chr++;
                }
                else
                {
                    chr = -1;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
```

This below code is pretty much explanatory iteself. I take the string which is within quoted and split them differently with only `'"' character`. Then I do SubStrings on outside quotes string and split them on `",", space and '"'` charaters. Please add your validations checks wherever needed to make it generic.

```
string input = "sample' \"string's are, more \"text\" making\" 12.34,hello\"pineapple sundays";

            List<int> positions = CharOccurs(input, '\"');

            string within_quotes, outside_quotes;
            string[] arr_within_quotes;
            List<string> output = new List<string>();

            output.AddRange(input.Substring(0, positions[0]-1).Split(new char[] { ' ', ',', '"' }));

            if (positions.Count % 2 == 0)
            {
                within_quotes = input.Substring(positions[0]+1, positions[positions.Count - 1] - positions[0]-1);
                arr_within_quotes = within_quotes.Split('"');
                output.AddRange(arr_within_quotes);
                output.AddRange(input.Substring(positions[positions.Count - 1] + 1).Split(new char[] { ' ', ',' }));
            }
            else
            {
                within_quotes = input.Substring(positions[0]+1, positions[positions.Count - 2] - positions[0]-1);
                arr_within_quotes = within_quotes.Split('"');
                output.AddRange(arr_within_quotes);
                output.AddRange(input.Substring(positions[positions.Count - 2] + 1).Split(new char[] { ' ', ',', '"' }));
            }
```

Comment: I understood this solution on my first pass. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is a more complex parsing problem than you fully appreciate. I suggest you look at the [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class  and the FileHelpers library: http://www.filehelpers.com/

Comment: Jim that is a really great resource, thanks for sharing that one, ill be using that on Monday!

Comment: I appreciate the resource but I can't have an external library in this project.

Answer (score 1):

I Wrote this Parse Line function a few months ago for VB.NET, it may be of some use to you, it works out if there are Text Qualifiers and will split based on the Text, ill try to convert it to C# for you in the coming few minutes if you want me to.

You Would have your line of Text:

sample' "string's are, more "text" making" 12.34,hello"pineapple sundays

and you would have that as your strLine 
and you would set your strDataDelimeters = ","
and you would set you strTextQualifier = """"

Hope this helps you out.

```
Public Function ParseLine(ByVal strLine As String, Optional ByVal strDataDelimiter As String = "", Optional ByVal strTextQualifier As String = "", Optional ByVal strQualifierSplitter As Char = vbTab) As String()
        Try
            Dim strField As String = Nothing
            Dim strNewLine As String = Nothing
            Dim lngChrPos As Integer = 0
            Dim bUseQualifier As Boolean = False
            Dim bRemobedLastDel As Boolean = False
            Dim bEmptyLast As Boolean = False   ' Take into account where the line ends in a field delimiter, the ParseLine function should keep that empty field as well.


            Dim strList As String()

            'TEST,23479234,Just Right 950g,02/04/2006,1234,5678,9999,0000
            'TEST,23479234,Just Right 950g,02/04/2006,1234,5678,9999,0000,
            'TEST,23479234,Just Right 950g,02/04/2006,1234,,,0000,
            'TEST,23479234,Just Right 950g,02/04/2006,1234,5678,9999,,
            'TEST,23479234,"Just Right 950g, BO",02/04/2006,,5678,9999,,
            'TEST,23479234,"Just Right"" 950g, BO",02/04/2006,,5678,9999,1111,
            'TEST23479234 'Kellogg''s Just Right 950g' 02/04/2006 1234 5678 0000 9999
            'TEST23479234 '' 02/04/2006 1234 5678 0000 9999

            bUseQualifier = strTextQualifier.Length()

            'split data based on options..
            If bUseQualifier Then
                'replace double qualifiers for ease of parsing..
                'strLine = strLine.Replace(New String(strTextQualifier, 2), vbTab)

                'loop and find each field..
                Do Until strLine = Nothing

                    If strLine.Substring(0, 1) = strTextQualifier Then

                        'find closing qualifier
                        lngChrPos = strLine.IndexOf(strTextQualifier, 1)

                        'check for missing double qualifiers, unclosed qualifiers
                        Do Until (strLine.Length() - 1) = lngChrPos OrElse lngChrPos = -1 OrElse _
                          strLine.Substring(lngChrPos + 1, 1) = strDataDelimiter

                            lngChrPos = strLine.IndexOf(strTextQualifier, lngChrPos + 1)
                        Loop

                        'get field from line..
                        If lngChrPos = -1 Then
                            strField = strLine.Substring(1)
                            strLine = vbNullString
                        Else
                            strField = strLine.Substring(1, lngChrPos - 1)
                            If (strLine.Length() - 1) = lngChrPos Then
                                strLine = vbNullString
                            Else
                                strLine = strLine.Substring(lngChrPos + 2)
                                If strLine = "" Then
                                    bEmptyLast = True
                                End If
                            End If

                            'strField = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", strTextQualifier, strField, strTextQualifier)
                        End If

                    Else
                        'find next delimiter..
                        'lngChrPos = InStr(1, strLine, strDataDelimiter)
                        lngChrPos = strLine.IndexOf(strDataDelimiter)

                        'get field from line..
                        If lngChrPos = -1 Then
                            strField = strLine
                            strLine = vbNullString
                        Else
                            strField = strLine.Substring(0, lngChrPos)
                            strLine = strLine.Substring(lngChrPos + 1)
                            If strLine = "" Then
                                bEmptyLast = True
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If

                    ' Now replace double qualifiers with a single qualifier in the "corrected" string
                    strField = strField.Replace(New String(strTextQualifier, 2), strTextQualifier)

                    'restore double qualifiers..
                    'strField = IIf(strField = vbNullChar, vbNullString, strField)
                    'strField = Replace$(strField, vbTab, strTextQualifier)
                    'strField = IIf(strField = vbTab, vbNullString, strField)
                    'strField = strField.Replace(vbTab, strTextQualifier)

                    'save field to array..
                    strNewLine = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", strNewLine, strQualifierSplitter, strField)

                Loop

                If bEmptyLast = True Then
                    strNewLine = String.Format("{0}{1}", strNewLine, strQualifierSplitter)
                End If

                'trim off first nullchar..
                strNewLine = strNewLine.Substring(1)

                'split new line..
                strList = strNewLine.Split(strQualifierSplitter)
            Else
                If strLine.Substring(strLine.Length - 1, 1) = strDataDelimiter Then
                    strLine = strLine.Substring(0)
                End If
                'no qualifier.. do a simply split..
                strList = strLine.Split(strDataDelimiter)
            End If

            'return result..
            Return strList

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(String.Format("Error Splitting Special String - {0}", ex.Message.ToString()))
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: No need to convert. I need it in vb for this solution. Thanks!

Comment: I use this same logic for over 400 weekly data loads, so it has been tested as well, also if this is the answer can you up vote please.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to display an underscore to indicate a space as before the ", like you show in your question you can use:

```
string[] splitString = t.Replace(" \"", "_\"").Split('"');
```

Comment: This is just so we see the space in the example, it isn't a desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions for this sort of thing get complicated *fast* as you start to add all sorts of exceptions.

None the less, if more for the sake of interest and completeness than anything else:

```
(?<term>[a-zA-Z0-9'.=]+)|("(?<term>[^"]+)")
```

Comment: Is it possible to alter that RegEx for escaped (double) quotes within quotes, as you would normally see in a text-qualified csv file such as exported from Excel or Access?